# Invoke many methods asynchronously and do something when each of them is complete

Tags: c#, task

So here is the deal. I have list of objects which all implement the same `interface`. Lets call this list `things`. since every `thing` in `things` implements the same interface I know that they have the method call `DoStuff(StuffParams stuffParams)`. I would like to invoke this method for each `thing` asynchronously and do something whenever each of them is complete. So to be more specific.

```
public void CreateSomething(Something something)
{
    ValidateSomething(something);

    someDAL.AddSomething(something);

    AddSomethingToMonitor(something);

    var things = someService.GetThings(); 
    // every thing in things has method DoStuff

    // invoke thing.DoStuff for each thing in things and return to caller
}

// when those methods return something should happen
// but I don't know where to write that code. Inside CreateSomething or outside.
```

I suppose I should use async and await keywords to achieve what I want but I have no Idea how.

Comment: I don't find your Edit an improvement. Try to indicate what should run on each thread, and what should happen on/with the main thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possibilities, including Tasks and `.ContinueWith()` but the most direct approach would be:

```
Parallel.ForEach (things, thing => 
{
    // Invoke thing.DoStuff with some specific parameters asynchronously.

    // Do something when a single one returns
});

// Do something when all  methods have returned.
```

Variations with e.g. Cancellation are possible.

Comment: will this execute on main thread ? I mean Before this statement some stuff happens and when that stuff is done this method thing should execute. for instance. I have a method add something to db. before I add anything I should check for validity and after checking and inserting data into db I want main method to return, but this thing.DoStuff s should be executed in background not blocking the main thread. I will make changed to my code and you will see.

Comment: It will run on multiple threads but it will block the calling thread until all is complete.